# Google Chrome, text input value

Tags: jquery

I have an authentication system in my program, and when I did 'Save Password' with google chrome, it automatically fills the username and password text boxes with the last username and password that was saved.

However, when I try to check the value of the content of the username input box, using:

```
alert($('#user_email').val());
```

Google Chrome gives me blank output, while Firefox gives me the value in the text box. Is there a way to get this value for Google Chrome as well? Maybe using something other than **.val()**?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running your `alert` manually after the page has loaded, or is it part of a script embedded in the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use it like this, after everything is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($('#user_email').val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome fills the textboxes after a slight delay once the page is loaded you may try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 setTimeout(showAlert,2000);
 });


  // this function will be triggered after 2 sec of document load
   function showAlert()
   {
       alert($('#user_email').val());
   }
```

Comment: i am using focus() event to show the text box contents, and at any point, even after i see that there is content in the text box, chrome shows null. anyways, i fixed my problem with another approach. Thanks anyways.